# How to remove @users and #hashtags from a tweet string

Tags: ruby, regex, twitter

I am trying to parse some tweets and I am having trouble using regular expressions to remove the words that start with an `@` symbol and a `#` symbol.
I have tried

```
tweet.slice!("#(\S+)\s?")
tweet.slice!("@(\S+)\s?")

tweet.slice!("/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!\d+(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/i")
tweet.slice!("/(?:\s|^)(?:@(?!\d+(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/i")

tweet.slice!("\#/\w/*")
tweet.slice!("\@/\w/*")
```

And none of them seem to work. Am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `tweet.gsub!(/[#@]\w+/, '')`

Comment: It worked! if you submit as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using `gsub!` and word boundaries.

```
tweet.gsub!(/\B[@#]\S+\b/, '')
```

Regular expression:

```
\B         the boundary between two word chars (\w) or two non-word chars (\W)
[@#]       any character of: '@', '#'
\S+        non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)       
\b         the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21):

```
>> tweet = 'Hello @ruby #world'
=> "Hello @ruby #world"
>> tweet.gsub!(/[#@]\w+/, '')
=> "Hello  "
>> tweet
=> "Hello  "
```